# How to set SAMESite cookie to none in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, samesite

I have web-app with reactjs(frontEnd) and springboot(Backend) on deployed on **two(2) different servers.**

They both are **http servers and NOT HTTPS**.

I searched all the stackoverflow questions related to this but none seem to work.

I am **not** using **spring-session** dependency or **Spring-security** dependency.

To maintain user session I am just making my beans **@SessionScoped** and it was working fine if everything was on **same server**, but on **different servers it has broked**.

Browser gives this error as **can't set samesite=none**, over **http for this https is required**.

So what is the workaround for this problem. As I can't have my server to be https as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using ResponseCookie. See below:

```
final ResponseCookie responseCookie = ResponseCookie
                .from("test", "test")
                .secure(true)
                .httpOnly(true)
                .path("/")
                .maxAge(12345)
                .sameSite("None")
                .build();
        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, responseCookie.toString());
```

Cookie name: test and Value: test.

Need set secure true to use sameSite("None").

This should save your Cookie